# Bitwise operators between String Java

Tags: java, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-or

I want to use bitwise operators between strings(stirngs has not the same length) in Java.

Actually, in case that I have two Strings

e.g **s1=test s2=sampleJAVA**

I convert strngs to binary:

**s1Binary=01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100**

**s2Binary=01110011 01100001 01101101 01110000 01101100 01100101 01001010 01000001 01010110 01000001**

And I want to calculate two bitwise operators

1. s1Binary | s2Binary
2. s1Binary & s2Binary

I tried for two strings:

```
 String s1 = "test";
 byte[] a = s1.getBytes();
 String s1Binary = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      s1Binary = s1Binary + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(a[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
  }
 /////// s2 /////
 String s2 = "sampleJAVA";
 byte[] b = s2.getBytes();
 String s2Binary = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
      s2Binary = s2Binary + String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(b[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0');
  }
```

But I stuck there because I have two strings with different  (binary) length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BigInteger like this.

```
String s1Binary = "01110100011001010111001101110100";
String s2Binary = "01110011011000010110110101110000011011000110010101001010010000010101011001000001";
BigInteger b1 = new BigInteger(s1Binary, 2);
BigInteger b2 = new BigInteger(s2Binary, 2);
System.out.println(b1.and(b2).toString(2));
System.out.println(b1.or(b2).toString(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pad the shorter string with leading zeros.

turn **01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100**

into **00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 01110100 01100101 01110011 01110100**